# WordPress block development TypeScript - useSelect type error

Tags: typescript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to use `useSelect` with TypeScript to get the current post type. In regular JavaScript, this code works fine (and is in fact code used in the main Gutenberg repo):

```js
const postType = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType(),
    []
);
```

However, when I convert to TypeScript, this throws a type error:

```
Property 'getCurrentPostType' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

I can't see what's causing it, why the return type is `<never>`.

The code actually does work and compiles fine, but I would like to get it type safe. Any ideas on how I can resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version are you using? It seems like similar issue to [Gutenberg issue #48133](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/48133) depending on version.